# node.js как убедиться в отсутствии блокирующего кода?

Tags: node.js

При подключении различных сторонних модулей весьма вероятно, что будет иметь место некая блокирующая операция.
Существует ли метод, помимо изучения работы того или иного модуля досканально, для выявления блокировки?

Answer (score 1):

Любой код блокирующий. Скорее всего имеется в виду io, либо тяжелые вычисления. К такого рода модулям и стоит присматриваться. Если методы такого рода модулей возвращают результат непосредственно - это 100% блокировка. Если это callback, promise или что-то подобное - то, вероятно, код асинхронный. Но 100% уверенность даст только анализ исходников.

Answer (score 0):

Эм.. Вызов любой операции блокирующий. До тех пор, пока где-то там внутри что-то не начнёт делаться асинхронно.

Ну и логика же. Если ты получаешь результат и (или даже или) не передаёшь коллбек, то 99% что либо операция синхронная, либо библиотека спроектирована криво.